# how to transform duplicate xml nodes in xslt and display the values in new line

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML and when i transform it i want the result to be in list with new lines. The child nodes have same name.

```
<books>
<bookname>Java</bookname>
<bookname>AJAX</bookname>
</books>
```

Expected result after XSLT transformation:

- Java
- AJAX

Comment: Please show us your expected result **as code** and explain what exactly is your difficulty in getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="//books/bookname">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
    </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        <xsl:for-each select="bookname">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: The above snippet lists the node values but in the same line. anyway thanks for your time to look into it. :)